# How to tell on which part of the screen divided to N rectangles am I (with mousemove)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to divide screen to 20 parts (horizontally) and set the value of mouse position from 1 to 20 to update sprite background-image position (for a smooth rotation animation). The code below is working, but there is a problem, when I move mouse very fast - than it can skip a few points, and I need to always change the number by one step. How can I achieve that?

https://codepen.io/kgalka/pen/vbpoqe

```
var frames = 20;
var frameWidth = Math.round(window.innerWidth / frames);
var xIndex;

function updatePosition(x) {
    if (xIndex != x) {
        xIndex = x;
        document.getElementById('val').innerText = xIndex;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    updatePosition(Math.round(e.clientX / frameWidth));
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example so its easer to test the solution we could provide.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kgalka/pen/vbpoqe

Comment: You need to *interpolate* between the 2 points, creating fake points.

Comment: @NikKyriakides I don't know what you mean, any chance for a codepen?

Comment: I've got no time myself but what I mean is that you need to [linearly interpolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) between the start point of your mouse entering the area and the last known point of the mouse within it. This will give you simulated (fake points) in between the 2. When you move the mouse too fast the browser doesn't report enough points so you have to create (fake) them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i saw th example and i think that i understand the problem and here is how i would fix this.

Have a look and let me know if it work.

```js
var frames = 20;
var frameWidth = Math.round(window.innerWidth / frames);
var xIndex;
var timeout;

function updatePosition(x) {
    if (xIndex != x) {
        xIndex = x;
      document.getElementById('val').innerText = xIndex;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
 // clear the prev call if the mouse was to fast.
  clearTimeout(timeout); 
  // Now ini new call to updatePosition
  timeout= setTimeout(()=>  updatePosition(Math.round(e.clientX / frameWidth)), 1 ) 
  // you could play with the timeout and increase it from 1 to 100ms. and see what you prefere
}
```

```html
<p id="val"></p>
```